# running php command with Symfony

Tags: php, windows, symfony, wamp

Until recently, I've used Symfony 1 and NetBeans IDE.  In Netbeans, I could use Symfony commands by clicking.

Now I would like start learning Symfony 2.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

I open cmd.exe and go to c:/wamp/www/Symfony and:

```
php bin/vendors install
```

But this doesn't work. It tells me it doesn't not recognize the name "php".

I use Windows 7, Wamp Server 2.1 (with PHP 5.3.5) and Symfony 2.0.5

How can i start with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added php to your windows path?

http://bobschwarz.com/quick-tip-adding-mysql-and-php-to-your-windows-path/