# Symfony2 > Quick Tour > The Big Picture: path to CSS and images is wrong

Tags: symfony

I've just started the "Quick Tour" from the Symfony2 website: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

The `config.php` file works (for me it's http://symfony2.local/config.php), including the CSS and images, which have relative paths such as:

```
bundles/framework/css/body.css
```

However, when I click the "Bypass configuration and go to the Welcome page" link, as instructed in the tutorial, I end up on http://symfony2.local/app_dev.php/, but the CSS and images don't show up. They have absolute paths, and they're all wrong:

```
/C:/bundles/framework/css/body.css
```

Is there anything I need to change in a configuration file somewhere?

Comment: probably need to execute a command read this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079337/running-php-command-with-symfony), then execute `php app/console assets:install` from your project root

Comment: @Andy Unfortunately the paths are still wrong.

Comment: Well to give a more clear answer, there is some important information missing like: What template engine do you use? How do you include the css file (yes with code), but just in case you use twig try to use this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="{{ asset('/bundles/framework/css/body.css) }}"/>` and you can always try to open the css file in the browser to see if it is really there, and then you should also have the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem didn't come from Symfony2, it came from my Apache configuration. Basically, the solution boils down to: remove the following line from the `httpd.conf` file:

```
FcgidFixPathinfo 1
```

See this question: 
[PHP $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is wrong when loading PHP via mod_fcgid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265469/php-serverscript-name-is-wrong-when-loading-php-via-mod-fcgid)